# string .join method confusion

Tags: python, string, join

I tried to join a sample string in three ways, first entered by the code and then entered by user input.  I got different results.

#Why isn't the output the same for these (in python 3.10.6):

```
sampleString = 'Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)'
ss1 = ' - '.join(sampleString)
print(ss1), print()

sampleString = input('please enter something: ')  #entered 'Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)'
ss2 = ' - '.join(sampleString)
print(ss2)

sampleString = input(['Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)']) 
ss2 = ' - '.join(sampleString)
print(ss2)
```

output:

```
Fred - you need a nap! (your mother)

please enter something: 'Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)'
' - F - r - e - d - ' - , - ' - y - o - u -   - n - e - e - d -   - a -   - n - a - p - ! -   - ( - y - o - u - r -   - m - o - t - h - e - r - ) - '

['Fred', 'you need a nap! (your mother)']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
sampleString = 'Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)'
```

Because of the comma, `sampleString` is a tuple containing two strings. When you join it, the delimiter is put between each element of the tuple. So it's put between the strings `Fred` and `you need a nap! (your mother)`.

When you do

```
sampleString = input('please enter something: ')
```

`sampleString` is a string. When you join it, the delimiter is put between each element of the string. So it's put between each character.

You can see this difference if you do `print(sampleString)` in each case.

Comment: I copied and pasted:

please enter something: 'Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)'
' - F - r - e - d - ' - , - ' - y - o - u -   - n - e - e - d -   - a -   - n - a - p - ! -   - ( - y - o - u - r -   - m - o - t - h - e - r - ) - '

Comment: Anything you type in response to `input()` is just a string, it's not parsed like a literal in code.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar.  Is there any way to achieve the same result with input?

Comment: you can use `ast.literal_eval(input("prompt"))` to parse the input.

Comment: If you enter it in response to `input()`, the brackets and quotes are treated literally, they don't create a list.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `sampleString = 'Fred','you need a nap! (your mother)'` is a `tuple` consisting of two strings. When you `join` them the separator (`-`) is put between them.

In the second case `sampleString` is just a `str`, not a tuple. So the separate is placed between each element (character) of the string.